# sort an array to fit another array with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

There is a number of questions out here concerning sorting arrays but I was not able to find the one solving my problem (which makes me hope that I'm not thinking way to complicated). So here we go:

I have two arrays with equal values but in different order:

```
a = np.array([4, 2, 5, 6])
# b = np.random.permutation(a)  # general case
b = np.array([5, 2, 6, 4])
```

I need the indices that sort b to a, so here:

```
ind = np.array([3, 1, 0, 2])
```

Note that I do not want to change a.

Comment: in this case, a is sorted ... is always true?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to make the example as easy as possible and actually made it too easy... Interchanged 2 and 4 in a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, `a` is already sorted. So, all you need are the sorting indices for `b`.

However, in case `a` was not sorted, you can do

```
a = array([2, 4, 5, 6])
b = array([5, 2, 6, 4])
b.argsort()[a.argsort()] # array([1, 3, 0, 2])
```

This uses the `argsort` method to return the indices needed to sort `b` and `a`.

Another example:

```
a = array([4, 2, 5, 6])
b = array([5, 2, 6, 4])
b.argsort()[a.argsort()] # array([3, 1, 0, 2])
```

Comment: this does not seem to work for arrays with non-unique elements:
`a = np.array([4, 4, 2, 5, 6])` and `b = np.array([5, 2, 4, 6, 4])`.

Comment: @leo. That's because there's a missing `argsort`.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The correct answer is `b = a[a.argsort()[b.argsort().argsort()]]` as given by @MadPhysicist below (but correcting the misplaced bracket).

Answer (score 4):

One approach with [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) & [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) -

```
_,C = np.where(a[:,None] == b)
```

Sample run -

```
In [210]: a = np.array([4, 2, 5, 6])

In [211]: b = np.array([5, 2, 6, 4])

In [212]: _,C = np.where(a[:,None] == b)

In [213]: C
Out[213]: array([3, 1, 0, 2], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Note that if `a` and `b` are large, this builds a boolean array of `len(a) x len(b)` which might be excessive depending on the use-case.

Answer (score 3):

`np.argsort` is its own inverse. If `y = x[x.argsort()]`, then `x = y[x.argsort().argsort()]`. Specifically, you convert `a` into a sorted array with `a.argsort()`, and convert from a sorted array to `b` with `b.argsort().argsort()`. You can therefore write:

```
b = a[a.argsort()][b.argsort().argsort()]
```

In other words:

```
ind = a.argsort()[b.argsort().argsort()]
```

Comment: The first code snippet should be `b = a[a.argsort()[b.argsort().argsort()]]` (note the closing bracket) as is clear from the second snippet.

Comment: @StenL. I'm pretty sure the two are equivalent based on my understanding of how indices work. If you have a counter-example, I'd be happy to shatter my world-view

Comment: Ah, you're right. Still, for anyone stumbling on this in the future, this is the correct answer and the one currently marked correct is incorrect.

Comment: This is very useful, especially in the case of very large arrays for which other options are much more computationally expensive